# How do I call the 'Recall Approval Request' via the Salesforce SOAP API?

Tags: api, soap, approval-process, leads

I've been asked by someone to recall a lead approval request via the API (soap). I've been able to submit a lead for an approval via the API by calling the process method, and it appears from the documentation that I can do the same for recalling the approval, but I'm not sure I'm understanding how I need to do this. I'm getting errors that are not even related to the process (ie.INVALID_OPERATION) so I'm doing something wrong.

This is my SOAP body:
<process xmlns="urn:partner.soap.sforce.com">
      <actions xsi:type="urn:ProcessWorkitemRequest">
        <action>Remove</action>
        <workitemId>04a1100000006URAAY</workitemId>
      </actions>
    </process>

where the workitemID is the ProcessDefinitionId from processInstance where TargetObjectId is my lead ID.

However, I'm getting the following response:

<processResponse>
  <result>
    <entityId nil="true" />
    <errors>
      <message>Illegal transition type</message>
      <statusCode>INVALID_OPERATION</statusCode>
    </errors>
    <instanceId nil="true" />
    <instanceStatus nil="true" />
    <success>false</success>
  </result>
</processResponse>

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I found out what the problem was. It was because I had set action as 'Remove' rather than 'Removed'.